# How to import a json file in vuetify?

Tags: json, vuetify.js

I am trying to import a json file in script like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import threadsjson from "../../public/sewing-thread.json";
    .....
</script>
```

But a red line shows under `"../../public/sewing-thread.json";` in Visual Studio Code. When I hover over `"../../public/sewing-thread.json";` it shows:

```
Cannot find module '../../public/sewing-thread.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extensionVetur(2732)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since yours is a JSON file it will not be having any export statement and hence you cannot use import by name. Instead, you can import everything with * and give it a variable name.
And then you can use the same in data.

```
import * as threadsjson from "../../public/sewing-thread.json";

....
....
  data() {
    return {
      threads: threadsjson
    }
  }
```